# C++ save screenshot to Buffer

Tags: c++, winapi, buffer, screenshot

this is my current function:

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <windows.h>

void screenshot()
{
    int screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    int screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow(); //Retrieves the window handle used by the console associated with the calling process.
    HDC hScreen = GetDC(hWnd); //possibly GetDC(NULL) instead? //Retrieves a handle to a device context (DC) for the client area of a specified window or for the entire screen.
    HDC hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreen); //Creates a memory device context (DC) compatible with the specified device.
    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreen, screenWidth, screenHeight); //the bitmap handle
    SelectObject(hDC, hBitmap);
    BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, hScreen, 0, 0, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT); //Performs a bit-block transfer of the color data corresponding to a rectangle of pixels from the specified source device context into a destination device context.

    //...enter "save to buffer" code here...//

    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hScreen);
    DeleteDC(hDC);
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
}
```

My objective is to create a function that when called, takes a screenshot and saves its data to the buffer. **my question:** What is the most efficient way to save it to the buffer, using ONLY win32 api? (add to buffer is the only part missing in the code).

Comment: Missing the line to actually save data to buffer

Comment: [Capturing an Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183402.aspx) provides a full code sample. Downvoted because this question *"does not show any research effort"*.

Comment: What buffer are you talking about?